# life and death of an object explanation

Tags: java

The code below gives me a warning on Eclipse: *"resource leak, input is never closed"*:

**Code: 1**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex {
    public void sum() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

I found that declaring the `input` variable in the class level does the trick, the warning is gone.

But, is this the right way of fixing this issue? And what is the difference between the second code and the third code? Does code 3 means that I have abandoned the first object?

**Code: 2**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex {
    private Scanner input;

    public void sum() {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

**Code: 3**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex {
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void sum() {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the downvotes here. It's a reasonably clear question thanks to the code snippets, and while the answer can be extracted from docs, so can answers to almost all questions at SO. Especially if you include the implicit queston of why Eclispe warns the way it does, it's not a trivial question.

Comment: @hyde  *"It's a reasonably clear question"*  Even a  clear question can show no research effort. And I guess this was the reason for the votes. If you think that this question shows a good amount of research (or has other qualities), then you're free to upvote it (but you already know that :D).

Comment: @hyde me neither ! , and i got the down vote like 2 seconds after i post the question , make me thinking does the down voter read it all  ?? ... thanks for noticing ^^

Comment: @Tom This question shows 3 code snippets, which were written to research the issue. I think that's more than enough research effort by SO standards... Anyway, commenting about seemingly strange up/downvoting is IMO quite reasonable here.

Comment: As a side note, it's possible to write annotations which disable a warning in Eclipse for the function. Those also serve as documenting the code. I'd write an answer showing how to do it in this case, if I were an Eclipse user, but perhaps someone else picks this ball.

Comment: @hyde *"I think that's more than enough research effort by SO standards"* Well, this is very subjective, hence the different votes. And what do you mean with "SO standards"? Are these standards defined somewhere? *"Anyway, commenting about seemingly strange up/downvoting is IMO quite reasonable here."* Has someone claimed otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *but , is this the right way of fixing this issue* - No its not... The input is still not closed, only that Eclipse is not able to detect it anymore... The issue is still present...

That being said, it's not a good idea to close the Standard input `System.in` too (closing the `Scanner` object would close the underlying stream too as I understand)... Hence it would be better to leave it like that even though there is a warning...

2. Yes, since in code 3 you have reinitialized `input`, you have abandoned the first object.

Answer (score 5):

The presence of a warning is almost always a sign of a problem. But the absence of a warning doesn't mean there is no problem.

The first snippet warns you that you're not closing the `Scanner` object when you're done with it. The proper fix would be to close it. Not to make your code worse by using a field instead of a local variable, and still not closing the scanner when you're done with it. That will make the warning disappear, but not the problem. Variables should always have the narrowest possible scope.

That said, A `Scanner` opened with `System.in` as argument, although it implements `Closeable` (that's why you have the warning), should in fact not be closed, because that would close the underlying stream: System.in. File or Socket streams must be closed, but `System.in` should generally not. If you close it, the user won't be able to enter anything anymore to your program.

Comment: i'm reading three text books of java , this the first time i know that Eclipse can miss an error , or the absent of warning doesn't have to  mean that the issue is fixed , thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the warning because the scanner instance is never closed. Modify the code: 1 as below to eliminate the warning,

```
public void sum() {
    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input  = new Scanner(System.in);
        // do operation
    } finally {
         input.close();
    }
}
```

Regarding code:2, declare any variable at Object level only when its required. i.e if it needs to be accessed by multiple member functions defined in the class.

To answer your question **is this the right way of fixing this issue , and what is the difference between the second code and the third code ? Does code : 3 means that i have abandoned the first object ?**

No, Code: 3 is not the right way way to fix the issue. And yes, code:3 creates a new instance of scanner inside the member function "sum" and the reference of the member variable input will point to the newly created scanner instance.

In summary, create a member variable (object level) only when its absolutely required, otherwise create a local variable - this will ensure that the objects get collected much earlier. (i.e. these objects will become eligible for GC when the method execution completes). Also, make sure that, call close() on almost all of the IO classes (stream classes) that we operate on.

Also, Note that if you close System.in, you won't be able to read from it again